# How to avoid reference to last index in a for loop while sending index as parameter for a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code:

```
function(targetSliderObject, images){
        // create thumbs container
        var thumbsContainer = $("<div></div>").addClass(defaultOptions.thumbsContainerClass);
        // add thumbs
        for(i in images)
        {
            thumb = $("<img />").addClass(defaultOptions.thumbItemClass).addClass(i);
            thumb.attr("src", images[i]);
            thumb.click(function(){
                methods.slideNext(targetSliderObject, i);
            });
            thumb.appendTo(thumbsContainer);
        }
        // add thumbs container to container
        targetSliderObject.append(thumbsContainer);
}
```

What I intend to do is calling method.slideNext() with a different number each time, but insted I get to send a reference to i as parameter for the function which, in the end, is the last index of my array for all my thumbs.

What trick can I use to accomplish what I want ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Anchor" the value of `i`:

```
(function(i) {
    // code that uses i
})(i);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I cand not make it work. I tried to use this "anchoring" in all the posible ways I could think of. Are you shure it should work? Can you give me a more detailed example?

Comment: I mention that the function above is an element of an object - the method object (if this information can help)..